# For loop not updating array from mongoose callback

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I think my problem is with the asynchronous nature of JS. I'm trying to push items in an array, but it doesn't seem to be updating it... I did console.log statements inside the for loop and see it populate the array with numbers, but when I console.log the array outside the loop, I get an empty array. I am using Mongoose. 
Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
let collections = [];
                return Promise.all(courts.map(court => {
                  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    return Promise.all(court.users.map(async user => {
                      let tempPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
                          setTimeout(() => {
                              resolve();
                          }, 5000);
                      });
                                  return SignDetail.find({
                                    userName: user.userName,
                                    signStatus: "signIn",
                                  }).then(function(sign) { 
                                    if (user.userName.endsWith('zs')) { 
                                        let signCount = 0;
                                        if (sign.length > 1) {
                                            for (let j = 0; j < sign.length; j++) {
                                                let courtObj = {courtName: sign[j].userName}; //make court object
                                                signCount++; //increment each time there's a signature
                                                if (j === sign.length - 1) { //only push object in array when all signatures have been counted
                                                    courtObj.signCount = signCount;
                                                    collections.push(courtObj);
                                                    console.log(collections)
                                                } 
                                            }
                                        } 

                                    } //end here
                                  }); 
                      return tempPromise;
                    })).then(_ => resolve(collections));
                  })
                })).then(collections => {
                  // HERE you will your collection and you can use this promise where this function is being called. 
                  console.log(collections);
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function SignDetail.find() is async function, you cannot return the res.render synchronously. You need to return a promise from this function which resolves to desired output.

You can do something like this.

```
let collections = [];
return Promise.all(courts.map(court => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return Promise.all(court.users.map(oUser => {
      var tempPromise = new Promise();
      if(oUser.userName.endsWith('zs')){
        SignDetail.find(
          {username: oUser.username. signStatus: 'signIn'}, 
          function(err, sign){
            collection.push(sign.length);
            tempPromise.resolve();
          })
      } else{
         tempPromise.resolve();
      }
      return tempPromise;
    })).then(_ => resolve());
  })
})).then(_ => {
  // HERE you will your collection and you can use this promise where this function is being called. 
  console.log(collections);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. When I put this code into my else block, I get an error saying Unhandled promise rejection warning: cannot read property map of undefined""

Comment: I edited it just now. changed court.user.map to court.users.map

Comment: Hello again. I was wondering why my code outputs collections as an array of an array as many times there are courts. For example, inside the promise when we do ```collections.push(courtObj)```, the console.log outputs only 1 item, but in the later console.log we get an array of arrays with courtObj 10 times if there are 10 courts.... The problem is with resolve(collections), but I don't know how to make it only output the correct original collection array. Example of collection array after resolve: ```[ [ { courtName: '1100zs', signCount: 9 } ],
  [ { courtName: '1100zs', signCount: 9 } ] ```

Comment: It was because let collections = [] was done inside court.users.map which was creating new array for each court.users. I edited it. Please check now.